# How would I get reference to my custom collection view cell inside the method that declares the GCSize?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a collection view with custom view cells..

I am trying to get the reference of the cell where it's defining the height:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;

    MyCustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DequeueMyCustomReusableCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, [cell calculatedHeight]);
}
```

This does not work..  What should I do?

Nor does this:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath does not work perhaps some cells are not visible.

Comment: It looks like the calculatedHeight returns 0, because it's not initialized yet?  But if I set it so the value is not 0, then it will enter this code:


      -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{...}

I wonder how to get the initialized reference to it...

Comment: Did you test if cell is nil?

Comment: It looks like it is nil..  So I've given a default GCSize for it.  When would it be able to enter the code that assumes it's not nil?

    if(cell == nil){
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, 300);
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, [cell calculateHeight]);
    }

Comment: If you use cellForItemAtIndexPath:,cell would be nil if it is currently not visible.

Comment: Yes, I understand this.  But it becomes visible afterwards.. after the GCSize has been set.  What should I do?

Comment: Well,you could add a class method for your MyCustomCell,and pass your data to that method to calculate that cell's height.Something like this [MyCustomCell prefferedSizeWithData:self.data[indexPath.row];

Comment: The Custom Cell has a class method which provides the height (e.g. [cell calculatedHeight]).  The problem is the cell is nil when I am trying to reference it within the GCSize collectionview method.

Comment: You don't have to get the reference any more,because that is a class method.Here is a post that might match your issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377516/uicollectionview-delegate-method-cellforitematindexpathindexpath-not-called-fro