# Setting cell height of CollectionView, doesn't really expand cell for scrolling

Tags: ios, autolayout

I can set the height of the cell and the content gets displayed, but I can't scroll down the collection-view, and if I have 2 items in my array the UITextView Content (in that custom cell) overlaps the start of the 2nd cell in the collectionview:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCellView* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DequeueReusableCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setHeight: [cell calculateHeight]];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set cell sizes manually. You need to let the collectionView layout the cells for you.

Assuming you're using a Flow layout, if you want a constant item size you just set the itemSize property on the layout, in IB or in code. If you need dynamic sizes, as it seems you do, you need to implement this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In answer to your question about how to calculate size, I'd do something like this:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellWithText:(NSString *)text width:(CGFloat)width
{
    UIFont *textViewFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textViewFont}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: I see.. Then can you shed some light on getting the reference of an existing cell within that method?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402620/how-would-i-get-reference-to-my-custom-collection-view-cell-inside-the-method-th?noredirect=1#comment48893808_30402620

Comment: The size is actually queried before the cell is created. You need a way to calculate the cell's height before the `collectionView` asks for it. I usually implement a class method on my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that can figure out what the cell size is from the model object I'm using to populate the cell.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense.  So that calculate height method is calling this:  CGSize size = [self.txtField sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.txtField.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];  So without initializing the cell, i would have to in the current class just match the font properties of the txt field + the width, then call it within that -(CGSize)... method, no?.. I see what you mean, thanks.

Comment: I usually create an NSAttributedString with the same font as whatever the text output view is I'm using, a label, a `UITextView`, etc. Then I use the `boundingRectWithSize:` method on `NSAttributedString` to get that. If you're using a textField that should always have a constant size, since a textField always only has one line.

Comment: Meant to say UITextView* but thanks I see what you mean

Comment: How would that code look like if you don't mind posting a snippet?  Much appreciated

Comment: Added a method implementation to the answer.