# Call a UICollectionView Cell in sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to be able to call my `UICollectionViewCell` class in the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function. Like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = MyCollectionViewCell()

    let itemHeights = cell.titleLabel.frame.size.height + cell.subtitleLabel.frame.size.height + 20 

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width - 30, height: itemHeights + cell.thumbnail.frame.size.height)

}
```

The problem is that `cell.titleLabel.frame.size.height`, `cell.subtitleLabel.frame.size.height`, and `cell.thumbnail.frame.size.height` are all returning `nil`. I assume this is because whenever `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is called, the cell has not loaded yet and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` has not been called, yet.

I need to know this because the `cell.titleLabel` can be multiple lines and widths which are set in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405063/setting-cell-height-of-collectionview-doesnt-really-expand-cell-for-scrolling

Comment: You shouldn't dequeue a cell in a function other than `cellForItemAt:`  Even if you do dequeue a cell, you won't get a cell that is populated with the values for that index path.  You will need to calculate values for the height based on the data for the cell, or use an automatic cell height and provide a reasonable `estimatedSize` for your cell

Answer (score 2):

`sizeForItemAt` is called before your `cell` is actually created and configured with the required data. That is the reason you don't get correct data that you need.

**Try this:**

Create a `dummy cell` in `sizeForItemAt` by `dequeuing` it from the `collectionView`. Configure the cell with actual data that you want to display. After configuring it get what data you need, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    //Configure your cell with actual data
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    //Calculate the size and return
}
```

Comment: Caution:  dequeueReusableCell was working dependably for me in sizeForItemAt through dozens of simulator runs, both iPhone and iPad, and many iPhone device runs, and then crashed the app when run on an iPad Air.  I'm having better results now with the sizingCell approach described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53786943/1473527